# Hiring process taking too long, now I have a visa problem and have to renew my contract with my old employer, what shall I do?

Tags: job-offer, recruitment, resignation, human-resources

Please find the below timeline for the Interview Process:

- 26th May: HR Contacted me to have my profile
- 1st Of June: 1st Round of Interview
- 3rd of June: 2nd Round of Interview
- 8th of June: 3rd Round of Interview
- 10th Of June: HR Called me to have the first level of Negotiation
- 26th Of June: HR Confirmed on the budget allocation and initiation of the offer letter.
- 3rd Of July: Received the system generated mail of Initiation of the offer letter.

Since 7th of July to 11th Of July: HR is continuously saying that out of 6 level of approval, 5 level is completed and only one level is pending for approval. It should not go to that level but has gone due to crossing the initial allocated budget. But they are sure about the receiving of approval and just trying to buy the time from me.

I am worried in this scenario. Post followup they are confirming the timeline but unfortunately nothing is working out and a new timeline is being communicated to me. Every time since 7th of July, they are saying that out of 6 levels, we have received 5 levels of approval and only single level is pending in the system.

Should I keep any hope further on this? My existing visa will get expired in first week of August and my current employer is pushing for renewal which I kept on hold. If the renewal process is initiated, it will be tough to get released.

Not able to understand what should I do now. Based on the HR verbal confirmation, should I Proceed to resign in my current employer?

Please suggest.

Comment: You're in a tough position. I don't think we'll be able to provide a good answer for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: So they confirmed the budget allocation and now are using that as an excuse that it is not confirmed? Stay with your current job and find a different new post.

Comment: @SolarMike: that happens all the time. Feels more like a paper work mishap and then malicious intent .Walking away seems like an extreme overreaction.

Comment: This is a good question for the site, but add a helpful title and an introductory paragraph summing up your question; "Hiring process taking too long, now I have a visa problem and have to renew my contract with my old employer, what shall I do?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick a definite date, in the very near future. If you have an offer letting in hand by that date, decide whether to switch jobs based on its terms, and if you are switching jobs give your current employer notice.

You can choose whether to tell the potential employer that you must have the offer letter by then. You also have the option of telling your current employer that you will have a definite decision on the visa extension on that day, and check whether that timing is acceptable to them.

If you do not have an offer letter by that day, inform your current employer that you definitely want to go ahead with the visa renewal, and forget about the other job.

Comment: Good answer, but I would add to notify the prospective employer about the deadline. The Visa issue is very real and perfectly good reason to do so. This may help moving things along and there is really nothing to loose.

Comment: @Hilmar Thanks. I have done some editing taking into account your comment.

Comment: Thanks Patricia for your valuable suggestion and it seems to be perfect. I have just now decided to wait till 14th of July and if it does not materialized, I will continue with my present employer. Will keep you updated about the last status.

Comment: Hi Patricia, there is a good news. I have received the long expected offer letter today.